Cookie will soon be rejected because it is foreign and does not have the “Partitioned“ attribute. cors settings
I have a question about how to fix this problem "Cookie will soon be rejected because it is foreign and does not have the “Partitioned“ attribute. cors settings".
Now I have frontend and backend on different domens because of different deploy services.
So i am using flask in backend:
cors settings
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}, supports_credentials=True)
i have also 2 functions, for example, register and logout:
@auth_bp.post('/register')
def register_user():

    data = request.get_json()

    errors = schema.validate(data)
    if errors:
        return jsonify({'error': errors}), 400

    user = User.get_user_by_email(email=data.get('email'))

    if user is not None:
        return jsonify({'error': 'User already exists'}), 409

    new_user = User(username=data.get('username'), email=data.get('email'))
    new_user.set_password(password=data.get('password'))
    new_user.save()

    access_token, refresh_token = create_access_and_refresh_tokens(new_user)

    decoded_access_token = decode_token(access_token)
    access_token_expires_in_seconds = decoded_access_token['exp'] - decoded_access_token['iat']
    
    decoded_refresh_token = decode_token(refresh_token)
    refresh_token_expires_in_seconds = decoded_refresh_token['exp'] - decoded_refresh_token['iat']
    
    response = make_response(
        jsonify({
        "message": "User created and logged in successfully",
        "tokens": {
            "access_token": access_token,
            "access_token_expires_time (seconds)": access_token_expires_in_seconds,
            "refresh_token_expires_time (seconds)": refresh_token_expires_in_seconds,
        }
    }), 201)
    
    response.set_cookie(
        'refreshToken',
        refresh_token,
        httponly=True,
        secure=True,
        samesite='None',
        path="/"
    )
    
    return response

and
@auth_bp.get('/logout')
@jwt_required(verify_type=False)
def logout_user():
    identity = get_jwt_identity()
    user = User.get_user_by_email(email=identity)

    jwt = get_jwt()
    jti = jwt['jti']

    token_type = jwt['type']

    token_b = TokenBlockList(jti=jti)
    token_b.save(user_id=user.id)

    response = make_response(jsonify({'message': f'{token_type} token revoked successfully'}), 200)
    response.delete_cookie(key='refreshToken', httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='None', path="/")

    return response


See about Partitioned attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Privacy_sandbox/Partitioned_cookies, I hope it helps you.

I also recently started seeing this warning for a flask page which was being open from other page within iframe. As @Eduardo mentioned, browsers are now adapting the Partitioned attribute for cookies. See some explanation here and here. But flask's response class does not implement it until I believe v3.1.0 or something.
My solution was to create and add the cookie header manually.
So, after make_response(...), when you add the cookie, instead of:
response.set_cookie('refreshToken', refresh_token, httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='None', path="/")

you can do:
response.headers.add('Set-Cookie', f'refreshToken={refresh_token}; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure; Path=/; Partitioned;')

and when you delete the cookie, instead of:
response.delete_cookie(key='refreshToken', httponly=True, secure=True, samesite='None', path="/")

you can do:
response.headers.add('Set-Cookie', 'refreshToken=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Secure; Path=/; Partitioned;')

Hope this helps you and/or someone else.
